# Crossdomain error in Jw player

Tags: jwplayer, m3u8, crossdomain.xml

I'm getting this "Cannot access m3u8: cross domain access denied" error in my JW Player.There is already an crossdomain.xml file in the server I'm trying to access and I can't change it, Can anyone tell me if it's possible to force the player to refer a different crossdomain.xml file say crossdomain1.xml from the server i'm trying to fetch the video from?

Answer (score 1):

The player itself is not looking for crossdomain.xml, the browser is and it will only accept the crossdomain.xml file that is located at the root of the *domain* that is hosting the requested resource. This includes subdomains so if I'm trying to embed http://example.website.com/playlist.m3u8, the browser will look for http://example.website.com/crossdomain.xml.

Also, is the player in HTML5 or Flash when you are seeing this behavior. When in HTML5, the browser is not looking for crossdomain.xml. Instead, it is looking for the CORS headers on the hosting domain to be set up properly.

For more information on all of this, please see the [Crossdomain File Loading support article](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1403679-crossdomain-file-loading).